# Extract href ID in html page using regular expression

Tags: c#, html, regex

I was trying to extract ID which is in HTML page within href. Html looks like below

```
<p>To register your account, please click the following link:</p>
<p><a href="https://abc-api-test.mywebsites.net:443/#/userreg/99978f1c-4c04-41ac-abcb-5039658a1f52" target="_blank">Complete registration.</a></p>
<p>If you have any questions please do not hesitate to contact us at <a href="mailto:muaccount@aol.net">
```

Basically I want to extract `99978f1c-4c04-41ac-abcb-5039658a1f52` value from the above.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
// specify Regular expression
Regex pageParser = new Regex(@"href=[""|']https://abc-api-test.mywebsites.net:443/#/userreg/(?<ID>[\S]*?)[""|']", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

// extract matches from your HTML
MatchCollection matches = pageParser.Matches(yourHtml);

//Iterate through each match
foreach (var m in matches)
{
      var id = m.Groups["ID"].Value;

      // do whatever you want with the ID
}
```

Comment: If you need to pass `https://abc-api-test.mywebsites.net ` as a parameter, how can I change the solution. I tried few options and looks like with this formatting character it bit tough though. Could you pl. give em bit of a guidence.